# Jquery ajax unload page error on chrome

Tags: javascript, django, google-chrome, jquery

Only event unload page call function ajax this die

```
$( window ).on('unload',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ajax_delete_support_models(12);
});
```

-ajax run

```
function ajax_delete_support_models(sm_id){
var token = getTokenFromBrown();
var data_submit = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken':token,'sm_id':sm_id}
var ajax_data =  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost/delete-support-models/',
    data :data_submit,
    async : false,
    error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.log(request);
    },
    success: function(data){
            console.log('ok success')
    }
});
```

}

-- debug this

code: 19

message: "A network error occurred."

name: "NetworkError"

- I using jquery ajax unload page error please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Chrome:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=321241

More discussion here: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/5b3ePr9rMVQ